# Inequality for $p$ vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Is it true for $2 \leq q \leq p$ that
$$
\|x\|_q\leq n^{\frac{p-q}{pq}} \|x\|_p
$$
where $x$ is an $n$-dimensional vector. I only need the inequality for $n=2$, so that would suffice. I'm just curious if it's true for any $n$. Just from plugging it into a graphing calculator I believe it to be true, but how would I prove it?

Comment: [This](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lVert x\rVert_q^{p }=\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert x_i\rvert^q\right)^{p/q}n^{p/q}
$$
and using convexity of the map $t\mapsto t^{p/q}$, one gets
$$
\lVert x\rVert_q^{p }\leqslant  \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert x_i\rvert^p  n^{p/q}
$$
or in other words,
$$
\lVert x\rVert_q^{p }\leqslant n^{p/q-1}\lVert x\rVert_p^p.
$$